# How to check whether there is within the class of the same class?

Tags: c#

I'am sorry for my Engilsh. I have some class like this:

```
public class MainClass
{
      public string message { get; set; }
      public MainClass forward { get; set; }
}
```

And have Main funcion, where I'am inizialize class and fill data(in real project I have data in JSON format, where class can be embedded itself in an infinite number of times) of class:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MainClass clasClass = new MainClass()
    {
        message = "Test1",
        forward = new MainClass()
        {
            message = "Test1_1",
            forward = new MainClass() 
            {
                message = "Test1_1_1",
                forward = new MainClass()
                {
                    message = "Test1_1_1_1",
                    forward = new MainClass()
                }   
            }
        }
    };
}
```

How do I get the number of nested class names , without knowing their number?

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly recommend following .NET naming conventions, with property names of `Forward` and `Message`. You can use attributes to change how they're represented in JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go forward and count!

```
int count = 0;
MainClass tempClass = clasClass;
while (tempClass.forward != null)
{
    count++;
    tempClass = tempClass.forward;
}
```

Also you can make this a bit smaller.

```
int count = 0;
MainClass tempClass = clasClass;
while ((tempClass = tempClass.forward) != null) count++;
```

Comment: Thank everybody for help!

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you just want recursion:

```
public int GetNestingLevel(MainClass mc)
{
    return mc.forward == null ? 0 : GetNestingLevel(mc.forward) + 1;
}
```

Or as part of `MainClass` itself:

```
public int GetNestingLevel()
{
    return mc.forward == null ? 0 : mc.forward.GetNestingLevel() + 1;
}
```

Or in C# 6, if you want to use the null conditional operator:

```
public int GetNestingLevel()
{
    return (mc.forward?.GetNestingLevel() + 1) ?? 0;
}
```

That could cause problems if you have *very* deeply nested classes, in terms of blowing the stack - but it's probably the simplest approach otherwise. The alternative is to use iteration, as per M.kazem Akhgary's answer.

Comment: Would be better if you could pass the selector and if it would be generic.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I'd add that if and when I needed it. I don't like premature generalization.

Comment: i often see similar questions with self-parent-child relations. A general approach would be great for LINQ queries.